# Oracle to Vertica database Replication Models are there any?

Tags: replication, database-replication, vertica

I am looking into  replicating in real time data from Oracle to Vertica database.
So far i can not find anything that is able to do this !!! 
But i have foung Tungsten replicator that seems to work well in Mysql to Vertica (havent test it yet).

 My Question is : 
  
 Is there any tools or ways of doing this (oracle => vertica)???
And if so how would updates would be handled ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WisdomForce - acquired by Informatica - does data replication between oracle and vertica.  http://www.wisdomforce.com/.

Comment: Is true !! it seems they do !! but they are closed as a steel box !!I can not get any info !!

Answer (score 0):

Look at Tungsten Replicator.  It replicates from MySQL/Oracle to Vertica and is fully open source (GPL V2).  You can find the Tungsten Replicator project at code.google.com.  (Disclaimer:  I work for Continuent and wrote a good chunk of the replicator code.)